# SMS Broadcast Receiver issue in API 17 (JellyBean)

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver, android-4.2-jelly-bean

Ive been trying to create an android application that shows a custom dialog on the screen when a SMS is received. The application works great on API 11 (GingerBread), but does seem to be shwoing anything on the JellyBean emulator, although it receives the message.

Below are the important lines of code from my Manifest file:

```
    <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

The code for the Broadcast Receiver:

```
<receiver android:name=".MessageReceiveBroadcast"
        android:enabled="true" > 
        <intent-filter 
            android:priority="2147483647" >
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Note that, I have also tried changing the android:priority to 999 and 2147483646, yet it shows nothing. What am I missing?

Comment: Is your code working in API 16 ?

Comment: Have you launched your app's UI Activity on the device at least once after you installed it?

Comment: @NiravRanpara I havent tried it on API 16. Will do it now. But would it really make a difference?

Comment: @user1990572 : yes . try in 15 also

Comment: @RaghavSood My app does not have an activity. The only activity is the custom dialog that is shown when a SMS is received.

Comment: You're going to need an Activity. In newer versions of Android, the user must have run your app at least once before Android sends broadcasts to it

Comment: @NiravRanpara OK, Thanks. I'll try it on API 15 and 16 and get back to you later.

Comment: @RaghavSood Thanks a ton. Adding a launcher activity worked. I think its kinda dumb though. Anyway, I can bypass that?

Comment: @RaghavSood, can you please specify a source for " in newer versions of Android, user must have run your app before Android sends broadcast to it" ?. I've never heard about this. Thanks.

Comment: @user1990572 It cannot be bypassed, sorry.

Comment: @OvidiuLatcu This change was introduced in Android 3.0, and has been ever since. I can't seem to find it in the official documentation, but I'll post back if/when I do.

Comment: @OvidiuLatcu The change is mentioned in tons of answers on SO and android-developers google group, though.

Comment: @OvidiuLatcu [Found it](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-3.1.html). It was introduced in 3.1, not 3.0. My mistake, sorry. See the points under subheading `Launch controls on stopped applications`.